# What is the difference between RACSequence and RACSignal

Tags: ios, functional-programming, reactive-cocoa

Maybe I'm totally missing this but according to the documentation on [ReactiveCocoa on their types](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/FrameworkOverview.md#sequences), RACSequences are signals.

However. I see examples where you have code like this:

```
RACSignal *letters = [@"A B C D E F G H I" componentsSeparatedByString:@" "].rac_sequence.signal;

// Outputs: A B C D E F G H I
[letters subscribeNext:^(NSString *x) {
     NSLog(@"%@", x);
}];
```

And also

```
RACSequence *letters = [@"A B C D E F G H I" componentsSeparatedByString:@" "].rac_sequence;

// Contains: AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH II
RACSequence *mapped = [letters map:^(NSString *value) {
    return [value stringByAppendingString:value];
}];
```

A lot of the examples have RACSequence and RACSignal. What's the difference between rac_sequence.signal or just subscribing to the signal itself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One is pull driven (`RACSequence`) and the other is push driven (`RACSignal`). From [here](http://rcdp.io/Signal.html):

> Push-driven means that values for the signal are not defined at the
>   moment of signal creation and may become available at a later time
>   (for example, as a result from network request, or any user input).
>   Pull-driven means that values in the sequence are defined at the
>   moment of signal creation and we can query values from the stream
>   one-by-one.

In your case, you make the `RACSignal` pull-driven, because you are already have its values.

Comment: That's a great way to explain it. Thank you. I assumed that ReactiveCocoa was largely pull driven.